# Unit Test on Angular directive that doesn't consider changes on element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a problem to make my unit test work.
In the broswer my directive works great but when I test it I have a fail test.
Here the code :

```
angular.module('helloWorldApp')
  .directive('helloworld', function () {

    var helloworld = {};

    class Hello {
        constructor(name) {
            this.name = name ;
        }

        SayHello() {
            //console.log('Hello ' + this.name);
            return 'Hello ' + this.name;
        }
    };

    helloworld.template = '<label for="name">Your Name </label> <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name"/><br/><div id="result"></div>';

    helloworld.restrict = 'E';
    helloworld.link = (scope,element,attrs) => { 
        scope.$watch('name', () => {
            if (scope.name) {
                let HelloMe = new Hello(scope.name);
                let helloStr  = HelloMe.SayHello();
                element.find('#result').text(helloStr);
                console.log(element.find('#result').text());
            };
        });
    };

    return helloworld;
  });
```

Here the test :

```
'use strict';

    describe('Directive: helloworld', function () {

      // load the directive's module
      beforeEach(module('helloWorldApp'));

      var element,
        scope;

      beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = angular.element('<helloworld></helloworld>');
        element = $compile(element)(scope);
      }));

      describe('Test', function() {
        it('Hello Lola', inject(function ($compile) {
          var inputElt = element.find('input');
          console.log(scope.name);
          inputElt.val('Lola');
          inputElt.triggerHandler('input');
          element = $compile(element)(scope);
          scope.$digest();
          console.log(scope.name);
          expect(scope.name).toBeDefined();
          expect(element.find('input').val()).toBe('Lola');
          expect(element.find('#result').text()).toBe('Hello Lola');
        }));
      });
    });
```

I understand that in unit test there is some differences than in the broswer. But the `$watch` does trigger in my test but it doesn't change the result div.

Thank you for your explanation.

EDIT : Fail test answer

```
LOG: undefined
LOG: ''
LOG: ''
LOG: 'Lola'
Chrome 38.0.2125 (Windows 7) Jasmine__TopLevel_
 Hello Lola FAILED
        Expected '' to be 'Hello Lola'.
        Error: Expected '' to be 'Hello Lola'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late.

Are you sure you pasted the right code?

Just changed `angular.module('helloWorldApp', [])` but I suppose you've already initialised this module somewhere else.

it works fine: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/yC8NFCVwBrn9wcM9xhAC?p=preview